# How do you route traffic from only one user through wireguard?

Tags: iptables, vpn, internet

With a wireguard configuration provided from a VPN company:

How do you modify `iptables` and `wg0.conf` to  **route only traffic from the user `vpn` trough wireguard's interface wg0**, leaving all other traffic untouched?

### reactions to comments and answers

When running suggested commands (by Hauke Laging) as `PostUp` script in `wg0.conf` results in the user sending traffic trough the wg0 interface but  still unable to reach internet, why?

```
#!/bin/sh
# up.sh

iptables -t mangle -nvL OUTPUT | grep -q 0x2a ||
    iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner test -j MARK --set-mark 42

grep -q '^42  vpn$' /etc/iproute2/rt_tables ||
    echo '42  vpn' >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables

ip route show table vpn | grep -q default ||
    ip route add default via 10.66.95.98 dev wg0 table vpn

ip rule | grep -q 0x2a ||
    ip rule add fwmark 42 lookup vpn prio 42
```

The configuration `wg0.conf` currently looks the following:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <Hidden>
Address = 10.66.95.98/32,fc00:bbbb:bbbb:bb01::3:5f61/128
DNS = <DNS>
Table = off
PostUp = up.sh

#Following 2 lines added in attempt to allow local traffic 
PreUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = <Hidden>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint = 185.65.135.224:51820
```

`ip route` returns following output:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 100
```

`ip route show table vpn` returns output

```
default via 10.66.95.98 dev wg0
```

`ip rule` returns

```
0:  from all lookup local
42: from all fwmark 0x2a lookup vpn
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

`iptables -t nvL` returns

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5465 packets, 1114K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2829  671K CONNMARK   udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* wg-quick(8) rule for wg0 */ CONNMARK restore

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 5450 packets, 1113K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5786 packets, 1203K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  961 1123K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.0/24       owner UID match 1002
 261M  414G MARK       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1002 MARK set 0x2a
  156 56019 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.0/24       owner UID match 1002
 261M  414G MARK       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1002 MARK set 0x2a
   77 48572 MARK       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1002 MARK set 0x2a

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6507 packets, 1310K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1281  209K CONNMARK   udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            mark match 0xca6c /* wg-quick(8) rule for wg0 */ CONNMARK save
```

When running `tcpdump -i wg0 -n` & `ping google.se` following returns:

```
17:48:43.496475 IP 192.168.1.2.33044 > 185.65.135.224.51820: UDP, length 1184
```

indicating that packets indeed reach the wg0 interface. However, the ping doesn't yield any results.

```
110 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 111603ms
```

Comment: You might be able to find a solution by looking into policy based routing.

Comment: A simpler way would be to create a network namespace, put the wireguard network interface into that namespace, and then put all processes of user `vpn` also into that namespace (for example, if he logs on). That has the advantage that this also works for multiple users, on the fly, or even for one user wanting to choose between those per application.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by

1. using `iptable`'s module `owner` to detect those packets
2. using `iptable`'s target `MARK` to set the packet mark to any not yet used value
3. create an additional routing table which sends all traffic through the VPN interface
4. using `ip rule` policy routing to select the special routing table for the marked packets

```
iptables -t mangle -nvL OUTPUT | grep -q 0x2a ||
    iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner test -j MARK --set-mark 42

grep -q '^42  vpn$' /etc/iproute2/rt_tables ||
    echo '42  vpn' >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables

ip route show table vpn | grep -q default ||
    ip route add default via 10.66.95.98 dev wg0 table vpn

ip rule | grep -q 0x2a ||
    ip rule add fwmark 42 lookup vpn prio 42
```

Comment: When using the suggested as a upscript in wg0.conf with "PostUp" results in all users going over vpn except the user "vpn" which dosent have internet connection at all.

#!/bin/sh
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner vpn -j MARK --set-mark 42
echo '42  vpn' >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via $(ifconfig -a wg0 | grep "inet " | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | head -n 1) dev wg0 table vpn
ip rule add fwmark 42 lookup vpn prio 42

Comment: @Maximus That is unreadable. Put so much code not into a comment, add it to your question instead (like I have done now). The `echo '42  test'` must be executed once only as it changes a file. Doesn't make sense to put it in a script. though. Please add the output of `ip route`, `ip route show table vpn`, `ip rule`, and `iptables -t mangle -nvL` to your question.

Comment: Hello again. I've yet to understand the flow of the platform. Thanks for your patience & tips. The requested command output have now been added to the question.

Comment: I belive this does not work since wireguard will automatically start sending all the computers traffic trough wg0. Somehow all other traffic must be stopped and only make sure to only let marked traffic trough, which does work with the suggested code.

Comment: @Maximus I must admit I do not see the problem. Except for connections to `192.168.1.0/24` because those packets do not get the necessary mark due to the first rule in `OUTPUT`. I assume the UID of user `vpn` is `1002`. You can try to understand the problem better by checking with `tcpdump -i wg0 -n` whether the packets of user `vpn` reach the VPN interface. And you can check whether the packets of a different user get marked: `iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner otheruser -m mark --mark 0` (must be at the end of the chain; doesn't do anything besides counting packets).

Comment: I see, it's indeed strange since it was able to be done with openvpn in a similar fashion (but it uses to much resources so lets swap). It's correct the UID of `vpn` is `1002`. Command output added and the results are intresting to say the least, seems like traffic can be sent trough the interface but not received?. On another issue, I did find why all users where going over the vpn. Turns out it's a default setting in `wg-quick` (routing all traffic trough vpn). It could be turned by adding`Table = off` to `wg0.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for all input so far. Regarding the unmarked `target = RETURN` packets. How would you mark these? Might be related to why the ping doesnt answer..?

Comment: @Maximus I would not mark those packets. I was just curious whether there were any. Is the source address (192.168.1.2) of your ping correct? I would assume that should be `10.66.95.98` instead. Of course, with the wrong source IP you don't get replies. You can correct that with `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 ! -s 10.66.95.98 -j SNAT --to-source 10.66.95.98`